# Compare syntax on While controller jmeter 5.0

Tags: time, while-loop, jmeter

My test plan have one step need to compare current time with constant time and it set in While Controller. When current time below than constant time, thread will go inside and do some steps.

But I have a problem with syntax on While controller. It always notices java.lang.StackOverFlowError. Here is my condition in While controller:

> ${__BeanShell(System.currentTimeMillis())} < Long.parseLong(vars.get("ASTime"))

ASTime: the constant time I set from the beginning.

How can I change syntax on While controller? Does anyone know about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with While Controller's syntax, the problem is with your condition. You should put the comparison inside the __Beanshell() function like:

```
${__BeanShell(System.currentTimeMillis() < Long.parseLong(vars.get("ASTime")),)}
```

Few things to consider:

1. According to JMeter Best Practices since [JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), in your case it would be [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy). The syntax would be exactly the same, to wit:

   ```
   ${__groovy(System.currentTimeMillis() < Long.parseLong(vars.get("ASTime")),)}
   ```
2. According to the same JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible.